# Angular 2 check validity on multiple input fields

Tags: validation, angular, input

I am building a Angular 2 application and i am using some of angular 2 built in validations like *maxlenght, minlength and pattern*. So in my code i have like 2 input fields which i validate like this.

```
 <div class="form-group form-group-sm">
    <label class="col-sm-5 control-label" for="firstname"
           [innerHtml]="'workorder.customer.user.firstname' | translate">Firstname:</label>

    <div class="col-sm-7">
        <input class="form-control" type="null-text" id="firstname" [(ngModel)]="user.firstName" #firstname="ngModel"
               minlength="2" name="firstname">


        <div [hidden]="firstname.valid || firstname.untouched" class="alert-danger">
            <div *ngIf="firstname.errors && firstname.errors.minlength">
                      <span [innerHtml]="'entity.validation.minlength' | translate:{min: 2}">
                                minimum 2 characters.
                      </span>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group form-group-sm">
    <label class="col-sm-5 control-label" for="lastname"
           [innerHtml]="'smartwork3App.workorder.customer.user.lastname' | translate">Lastname:</label>

    <div class="col-sm-7">
        <input class="form-control" type="null-text" id="lastname" [(ngModel)]="user.lastName" #lastname="ngModel"
               minlength="2" name="lastname">


        <div [hidden]="lastname.valid || lastname.untouched" class="alert-danger">
            <div *ngIf="lastname.errors && lastname.errors.minlength">
                <span [innerHtml]="'entity.validation.minlength' | translate:{min: 2}">
                    minimum 2 characters.
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

This works fine. So if i type just 1 character, i will receive feedback that it requires minimum of 2 characters.

but how do i validate multiple fields like this when i click on a button. They have to be validated before the button can actually run his function.

Comment: have you followed the angular guide on this? I'm pretty sure they cover exactly what you are trying to do

Comment: yes you are right, but i have multiple input fields from different directives and the button is also in another directive. So i can't use the guide. Angular 1 has a simple trick. you can install _angular-bootstrap-show-errors_ and than use like this: `$rootScope.$broadcast('show-errors-check-validity')`, but unfortunately this does not work for Angular 2